# why is this array showing and error message(Eclipse)

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, error-handling

```
int[] myArray = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};        

for(int number : myArray) {
    System.out.println(myArray[number]);
}
```

and this is the output:

```
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
    at javaPractice.selfAssignArrays.main(selfAssignArrays.java:10)
```

what's wrong with it?

Comment: What do you think is right with it? What does `myArray[number]` do? What is each value of `number` at each iteration? What is the base index of an array?

Answer (score 1):

You want to do this:

```
for (int number : myArray) {
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

This is equivalent to this:

```
for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++)  {
    int number = myArray[i];
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

Comment: The `"" +` isn't necessary; `System.out.println(number);` will do the same thing.

Comment: Yes you are right. Been doing too much Android where `setText()` is a strict string type. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because the enhanced `for` loop sets `number` to each *value* in `myArray`, not to each index. (Note that the first element being printed is 2, which is the element at index 1.) Your enhanced `for` loop is more or less equivalent to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    int number = myArray[i];
    System.out.println(myArray[number]);
}
```

What you want is:

```
for (int number : myArray) {
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For each iteration, you get the number from array, and you take the number as the index. that's why ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException happened.

> System.out.println(myArray[1]); System.out.println(myArray[2]);
>   System.out.println(myArray[3]); System.out.println(myArray[4]);
>   System.out.println(myArray[5]); System.out.println(myArray[6]);
>   System.out.println(myArray[7]); System.out.println(myArray[8]);
>   System.out.println(myArray[9]); System.out.println(myArray[10]);

Get it?
You should start from `System.out.println(myArray[0]);` and end at `System.out.println(myArray[9]);`
Alternatively, just output the number as `System.out.println(number);`